# Several JavaScript Objects are absolutely identical

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

`steps["main_algorithm"]` is filled with objects of the main_algorithm_structure.
`main_algorithm_structure["loop1"]` is filled with objects of the loop1_struct.
(The struct or structure objects are always copied with `Object.create()` or `Object.assign({}, 'structure_name')`)

**The Problem is** different objects of main_algorithm_structure, that means at the end different objects of `steps["main_algorithm"]` have the exact same loop1 object. I am trying to solve that problem for days now.. i am very desperate and this bug needs to be fixed...

Look at the Java Script Logic below those objects.

```
    let steps = {
        "str_to_hash" : "",
        "init_constants" : [],
        "input_to_bit_translation" : [],
        "input_length_preprocessing" : [],
        "final_input_preprocessing" : [],
        "final_input_preprocessing_result" : [],
        "main_algorithm" : [],
        "hash_digest" : "",
    }

    let main_algorithm_structure = {
        chunk_number : undefined,
        chunk_preprocessed : undefined,
        loop1 : [],
        preConstants : undefined,
        loop2 : [],
        old_constants : undefined,
        new_constants : undefined
    }

    let loop1_struct = {
        lp1_sh1 : undefined,
        lp1_sh2 : undefined,
        lp1_add1 : undefined,
        lp1_add2 : undefined,
        lp1_s0 : undefined,
        lp1_s1 : undefined,
        lp1_y : undefined,
        lp1_w : []
    }
```

In the last `if(crSteps)` - Block, a copy of the loop1_structure is filled with data. This loop1_structure is pushed to `main_algorithm_structure["loop1"]`. Later in the algorithm this main_algorithm structure is further filled with data and at the end pushed to `steps["main_algorithm"]`. At the end of the whole script, the structure steps is returned by the function.

In every object of `steps["main_algorithm"]` the loop1-array is exactly the same. Why?

I hope the for-loop is everything which is needed to find the bug:

```
for(let x = 0; x<chunks.length; x++) {

    if(crSteps) {structCopy = Object.assign({}, main_algorithm_structure)}
    if(crSteps) {structCopy.chunk_number = x}


    //chunking every 512 bit chunk into 32 bit chunks -> w's result is 16 32 bit chunks
    let w = chunker(chunks[x], 32)

    //adding 48 32 bit chunks (every chunk is full of zeros)
    for(let m = 0; m != 48; m++) {
        w.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    }

    if(crSteps) {
        let toPush = []
        for(let c = 0; c<w.length; c++) {
            let temp = ""
            for(let c_ = 0; c_<w[c].length; c_++) {
                temp += String(w[c][c_])
            }
            toPush.push(temp)
        }
        structCopy["chunk_preprocessed"] = toPush.slice()
    }



    for(let y = 16; y<64; y++) {

        const sh1 = y-15
        const sh2 = y-2

        const add1 = y-16
        const add2 = y-7

        const s0 = XORXOR(rotr(w[sh1].slice(), 7), rotr(w[sh1].slice(), 18), shr(w[sh1].slice(), 3))

        const s1 = XORXOR(rotr(w[sh2].slice(), 17), rotr(w[sh2].slice(), 19), shr(w[sh2].slice(), 10))

        w[y] = add(add(add(w[add1].slice(), s0), w[add2].slice()), s1)


        if(crSteps) {

            let copy_loop1_struct = Object.create(loop1_struct)

            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_sh1 = sh1
            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_sh2 = sh2

            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_add1 = add1
            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_add2 = add2

            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_s0 = s0.slice()
            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_s1 = s1.slice()
            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_y = y

            let toPush= []
            for(let c = 0; c<w.length; c++) {
                toPush.push(w[c].slice().join(""))
            }
            copy_loop1_struct.lp1_w = toPush.slice()
            structCopy.loop1.push(copy_loop1_struct)


        }

    }
```

Comment: 1/2 ... I'm not able to exactly follow everything the OP says, but since the OP mentions ... _"is pushed to `main_algorithm_structure["loop1"]`"_ ... and the code shows something like ... `structCopy = Object.assign({}, main_algorithm_structure)` ... and later ... `structCopy.loop1.push(...)` ... this means following ... `main_algorithm_structure` gets merged into an empty object and its result gets assigned to `structCopy`. Now, due to the nature of `Object.assign`, which only copies the first level entries of an object, `structCopy.loop1` still holds a reference ...

Comment: 2/2 ...  into `main_algorithm_structure.loop1` which is an array-object already at a nested level deeper than 1. Thus the OP should try something like ... `structCopy = structuredClone(main_algorithm_structure)` ... see ... [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) ... which happens to not yet be supported by all JS environments/clients; but there are polyfills and/or alternatives for the deep-cloning of data-structures.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSeliger for your advices and explanations. The structuredClone method is very interesting, didnt know about that method. I continued working on that problem and i moved those object-structures to the places where i needed them. To be exact, i replaced `if(crSteps) {structCopy = Object.assign({}, main_algorithm_structure)}` with the whole definition of the main_algorithm_structure and i did the same with the structure of loop1_struct. With doing that the problem was solved. I will try to solve that problem again, with the old code and your information. :)